# Django: Exception Value 'Gifts' object is not iterable

Tags: django

Doing this causes error

```
gifts = get_object_or_404(Gifts)
```

While doing this does not.

```
gifts = Gifts.objects.all();
```

> Django: Exception Value 'Gifts' object is not iterable

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect, get_object_or_404
from .models import Gifts
    def home(req):
        gifts = get_object_or_404(Gifts)
        #gifts = Gifts.objects.all()
        return render(req,'gifts/gift_home.html',{"gifts":gifts})
```

Comment: because`Gifts.objects.all()` returns a **`Queryset`** (an iterable) while `get_object_or_404` returns a ***specific `Gifts` object***, which is not a iterable

Answer (score 0):

`get_object_or_404` will only return one object and if you want a list than you should use `get_list_or_404`. and also you have to filter with both these methods as `get_object_or_404(MyModel, pk=1)` and  `get_list_or_404(MyModel, published=True)`